# Docker - Supervisord container with Nginx (sudo user)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, supervisord, ubuntu-20.04

I have created a base image with `supervisord` installed.

Summary of steps:

`FROM ubuntu:20.04`

- Then I installed some base utilities (time zone/nano/sudo/zip etc)
  `FROM current_timezone/base-utils:1.04`
- Then I created a base supervisord image including a **user with sudo privileges and password.**

  ```
  RUN apt-get update \
      && groupadd ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_WEBGROUP} -f \
      && useradd -m -s $(which bash) -G sudo ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_USERNAME} \
      && echo "${DOCKER_CONTAINER_USERNAME}:${DOCKER_CONTAINER_PASSWORD}" | chpasswd \
      && usermod -aG www-data ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_USERNAME}
  ```

So in any Docker image deriving from this I can run supervisor :

```
  USER ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_USERNAME}
  CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]`
```

So, I have `Dockerfile` entries for my images deriving from this image :

- Apache
- Nginx
- Varnish
- etc

Most of the applications can launch with supervisord like this:

```
  [program:apache2]
  command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"
  autorestart=false
  startretries=0
```

But Nginx doesn't launch, the error:
*the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1*

So I created this and thought I would get an input prompt once the container starts: *(the objective was to receive input prompt when container starts so that password can be sent to `sudo -S` to start Nginx)*

```
  [program:nginx]
  command=sudo -K && read -s -p "Nginx requires a super-privileges (sudo user) to start - Please enter password for your sudo user: " TMP_PW && echo $TMP_PW | sudo -S service nginx start && unset TMP_PW
  user=userdefinedinstagesupwards
```

Running that command above in command-line **once I am inside the container already** `(docker exec -ti container_nginx bash)` works, and I can input password from command-line.

### The Issues

- Nginx does not start automatically, and I have to enter container to start Nginx manually.

NOTE: I have seen the docker nginx image
`docker run -d -v $PWD/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf nginx` but this **only has Nginx** - I have some tools I would like to reuse (as explained above I created an image that has those installed) which means I would have to recreate the steps backwards *just for Nginx*.

#### Additional information

As requested below by users, the reasoning why I am using supervisord like this is because I run multiple scripts (debug info/dynamic paths/secrets) and the main application (eg. Apache/Nginx/Varnish) etc alongside.

A simple example:  `Apache web-server` with two files (tried to make a brief example):
When supervisord initializes (`CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]`) the main application starts, and the helper scripts (in this example some environment variables built from *parent images*).  I can then access *all output in `/var/log/supervisor/app-stdout(or stderr)*` as required.*

For instance: I then have information on `${INSTALLED_BASE_APPS_TEXT}` available which tells me which apps my base-utils are installed.  If I ever see I need to add another tool, for argument here let's say `htop`, I can go and update the **parent image and rebuild this child stage later**.   Some tools I would always like to be available regardless of which container is running - `nano`,`zip` etc are things permanently used by me.

- **supervisor/conf.d/config-webserver.conf**

  ```
  [supervisord]
  nodaemon=true

  [program:apache2]
  command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"
  autorestart=false
  startretries=0
  ```
- **supervisor/conf.d/config-information.conf**

  ```
  [program:echo]
  command=/bin/bash -c "echo Loaded Supervisord program 'echo' - Stage 5 operation \(Custom Nginx supervisord config\)"
  autorestart=false
  startretries=1

  [program:echo_base_utils]
  command=/bin/bash -c "echo ${INSTALLED_BASE_APPS_TEXT}"
  autorestart=false
  startretries=0

  [program:echo_test_item]
  command=/bin/bash -c "echo ${ENV_TEST_ITEM}"
  autorestart=false
  startretries=0
  ```

### QUESTION

Is there any way that **supervisord** commands can be made so that they prompt for input as soon as container starts?  I would like to keep using the images described above.

Comment: Why are you trying to bring tools like supervisord or sudo into this?  Neither should typically be necessary.  (You can get a root shell in a Docker container via `docker exec` whenever you like, without hard-coding a plain-text password into your image; you only need supervisord if you're running more than one process in a container, which isn't usually a best practice.)  A [mcve] showing a complete end-to-end path for one thing would probably be a little clearer.

Comment: I have seperate scripts that also run on startup alongside the main application (ie. apache/nginx/varnish) containers that gives me output information, everything readable in `/var/log/supervisor/app-stdout-****.log`. These are just helper scripts to determine paths dynamically/debug information/secrets.  So, in essence unless I manage to radically change this supervisord part (which derives from my previous images as base - reusable to all child images).  This allows me to add/remove startup commands as I need for the current image.  (I will update supervisor information above with example)

Comment: Please see above update `Additional Information`

Comment: "without hard-coding a plain-text password into your image; " Also - this is not what I am doing at all, I use a bash script to prompt `read -s -p "Password: " DOCKER_CONTAINER_PASSWORD` as ARG, so on docker history I do not see the password.